# .htaccess redirect not properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect my pages in the following ways:

```
www.example.com/index.cfm?locale=it -> www.example.com/it
```

and I would like to access the same page when I type:

```
www.example.com/it
```

I wrote an htaccess file but it causes a redirect loop. Here is the file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#REWRITE RULES
#---------------------

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^locale=(it|en|fr|de|es)$
RewriteRule ^index\.cfm$ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.cfm
RewriteRule ^(it|en|fr|de|es)/?$ index.cfm?locale=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Could you help me to resolve it?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it this way.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
Rewrite ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.cfm\?locale=(it|en|fr|de|es)
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(it|en|fr|de|es)/?$ index.cfm?locale=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried this, but not convert from: www.example.com/index.cfm?locale=it -> www.example.com/it. From www.example.com/it it works anyway. Other ideas?

Comment: that is a 302 so it should't cache, but try and clear you cache anyway

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. www.example.com/index.cfm?locale=it didn't became www.example.com/it as I would like.

Comment: I solved the problem including in my code the "exit now" condition:
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
This condition goes before the other rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/it[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/it/$1 [r=301,nc]

//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 www.example.com/index.php?locale=it www.example.com/it

//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 www.example.com/index.php?locale=it(.*) www.example.com/it/$1
```

Comment: I have to redirect dinamically. I need to use %{QUERY_STRING} to solve my problem. How you can see from my code, I would like to redirect to other language, too.